# Extract telephone numbers from a column of address details

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of data in Excel like this:

```
bbbbbb
dsfasdfa
sdfdfdfdf
(444) 444-4444
```

There are about 4,000 similar records in the same column. I want only to extract the 'phone numbers in the above format and copy to a separate column.

Can anyone suggest a good formula?

Comment: (a) What have you tried? (b) Are the non-phone number entries all text as your example suggests? (c) Is the phone number always of the format `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the limited information available, copying the list to a bank column, sorting that column A>Z and deleting cells from the first that is not a telephone number to the end would seem adequate.